# Chrome extension - send message from content script to the pop-up

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I just wanted to ask you if it's possible to send a message from content script to the popup script. It works the other way around - from popup to content:

***popup.js***

```
let counter = 0;

let userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").addEventListener("click", () => {
    counter++

    let params = {
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }

    chrome.tabs.query(params, gotTabs);

    function gotTabs(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, counter)
    }
});
```

***content.js***

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);

function gotMessage(message) {
    console.log(message)
}
```

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello there!</h2>
        <button id="userInput">Click me!</button>
    </body>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

My question is, how can I send a **message from content script to the popup script**, if its possible, because when I switch those files, i got errors like:

*content.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.myClickHandler*

Thanks for your help.

Comment: chrome.tabs cannot be used in content scripts so you can use chrome.runtime.sendMessage (only when the popup is shown) or simply keep your current approach and add sendResponse as shown in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple).

Comment: @wOxxOm, but the problem with `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` is that it sends message to ALL the tabs, when I need to just the active one...

Comment: chrome.runtime.sendMessage doesn't send message to tabs. It sends to the extension's background script and other extension pages, not web pages.